# while entering image link in ibmq in python creating errors

Tags: image

Finding error in the path line. SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 7)
how to solve?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
from io import BytesIO
import os


out = BytesIO()
path='C:\Users\USER\Desktop\'

with Image.open(os.path.join(path,"flower.jpg") as img:
    img.save(out, format="jpg")
    image_in_bytes = out.getvalue()
    encoded_b2 = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in image_in_bytes])
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Anyone please help....

Answer (score 0):

Change `path='C:\Users\USER\Desktop\` to `path='C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\`

In a Python string, the `\` [backslash character is used as an escape character](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) to indicate that the next character is part of the string, even if otherwise illegal. For example, if your string needs to contain quotation marks, you would escape them.

```
print('He said, \'Good morning\'')
```

will print

```
He said, 'Good morning'
```

where not escaping the quotation marks would cause errors.

Your code includes a `path` string with backslashes, `path='C:\Users\USER\Desktop\'` , and Python believes you are intending to escape the U in Users and USER, and the D in Desktop, and the closing quote. (Escaping the other characters may cause you other problems later.) As the closing quote is now part of the string, the string hasn't actually been closed at all yet. It basically doesn't see the closing quote at all. Hence: "unterminated string literal".

You want your path string to include backslashes, but you do not want Python to interpret them as escape characters. The clever solution to that is to escape the backslash escape characters themselves, so Python interprets them as just backslash characters and not as escape characters. The first backslash of `'\\'` functions as an escape character and tells Python to treat the next backslash as just a normal character.

Comment: I am trying this code but it is continuously showing me this error  " [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flower.jpg'  "  but i saved a picture on my desktop and i copied the location from my desktop address..,..pleasse help...                                                     from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
out = BytesIO()
with Image.open("flower.jpg") as img:
    img.save(out, format="jpg")
image_in_bytes = out.getvalue()
message = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in image_in_bytes])

Comment: I tried this also but same error... import os
for f in os.listdir("C:/Users/USER/Desktop"):
    print(f)

Comment: sir kindly help.

Comment: You're now dealing with a different problem and I don't actually have either enough information about the new problem or the tools I'd need to speculate (not a python expert, and it's not installed at the moment). Maybe see [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory). If you're still having problems I'd encourage a new question, and make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).